# Двустронний пинг на 2ip.ru/privacy

Tags: http, запрос

Помогите разобраться откуда берутся данные для составления отчета. 
Задача стоит - определить используется ли на проксе туннелирование. Сервис 2ip/Privacy умеет определять. Вот я и хотел с него данные взять. 
При нажатии на кнопку "Проверить" запускается javascript. отловил все запросы после этого момента. 
Но не смог понять какой запрос возвращает нужную мне информацию.

Исходя из статьи с Хабра(от одно из авторов вышеупомянутого сервиса) проверка на туннель происходит с помощью отправки пинга от браузера к серверу и от сервера к заявленному ip. Если разница пингов > 30, то используется туннель.

Сервис шлет запрос на http://2ip.ru/?area=ajaxPing
в ответе или пусто или JSON с пингом
Это пинг браузер-сервер или та самая разница?

Если первое, то где найти пинг сервер-ip(или результат этого действия)

Надеюсь понятно объяснил, что мне нужно. На всякий случай сформулирую по точнее:
Меня интересует алгоритм запросов. 
1. GET - [http://2ip.ru/Privacy(Получает](http://2ip.ru/Privacy(%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82) PHPSESSIONID)
А что дальше?

Comment: Вот пара проксей с туннелями 
77.73.65.165:8080 HTTPs
213.24.63.116:3128 HTTPs

Answer (score 0):

Раз никто не отвечает...
Решил свою задачу иначе. 
Раз единственная защита от проверки двусторонним пингом - это запрет исходящего ICMP трафика, то я просто пинговал видимый IP. Если пингуется - значит туннель определится, нет - нет.